# Create a random youtube video player

Tags: javascript, arrays, video, youtube, youtube-api

I want to create a youtube video player that rearranges an array of videos each time the webpage is accessed, and then plays them in that that arranged order.

So far my code is able to pick a random video from the array play it, then randomly pick another video and play it.

The issue with this is that the videos overlap. When it randomises the array I want all of them to play in sequence: like 3,2,1 or 2,1,3 or 3,1,2. With no repeats.

At the moment it will play any video of the 3 any number of times.

This function will shuffle the array each time the page is accessed, this section works.

```
function shuffle(array) {
        var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

        // While there remain elements to shuffle...
        while (0 !== currentIndex) {

          // Pick a remaining element...
          randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
          currentIndex -= 1;

          // And swap it with the current element.
          temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
          array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
          array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
        }

        return array;
      }
```

This is code adapted from https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

```
  // 1. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 2. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  var list = ['rgAYRbeO9GI','6wKxfH9NpVE','OJ9qLosjjH8']
  shuffle(list); // shuffles the array


  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '585',
      width: '960',
      // videoId: list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)],
      videoId: list[0], // accesses the first index of the newly sorted list array, Ideally I want to play the next video
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 3. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 4. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED && !done) { // once the video is finished the onPlayerReady() function repeats.
      onPlayerReady();
      done = true;
    }
  }
```

I need a way to move form the list[0] index to the next, I'm not sure where to put the loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to randomise a youtube playlist using this code:

```
var playlistLength = 198;
function onPlayerReady(event) {
          player.cuePlaylist({
          'listType': 'playlist',
          'list': 'PLCEwouDaI4SXpFtD8wVnPY7wfx7LpXXRw',
          'index' : [Math.floor(Math.random() * playlistLength)]
         });

setTimeout( function() { 
          //event.target.stopVideo();
          //event.target.playVideoAt(3);
          event.target.setShuffle(true); 
          event.target.playVideo();
          event.target.setLoop(true);
          }, 
        1000);
      }
```